# What Java version do I need to install to run the Ardor blockchain public server node?

Tags: java

I am trying to run compile.sh for the Ardor public node server. But the latest Java 11 isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable option is  to install Java 8 on ubuntu like this:

> apt install openjdk-8-jdk